# How to apply delete in alert function ionic?

Tags: laravel, ionic3, laragon

I have applied Laravel code and test the API to delete data and it succeeded.

Now I want to apply the function delete to ionic. How Can I apply it on alert function?

**.ts file**

```js
confirmdelete() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm Delete',
    message: 'Do you confirm to delete?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Yes clicked');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

So I having problem to do the delete in the ionic. What I think there something I need to include in the yes handler or what? Im still not sure.

**api.php**

```php
public function deleteMed(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $medname = $request->medname;
    $price = $request->price;
    $stock = $request->stock;
    $medno = $request->medno;
    $ingredient = $request->ingredient;
    $description = $request->description;
    $addinfo = $request->addinfo;

    $user = AddMedicine::where('medno',  $request->input('medno'))->count();

    if($user!=0) {
        AddMedicine::where('id', $id)->delete([
            'id' =>$id,
            'medname'=>$medname,
            'price'=>$price,
            'stock'=>$stock,
            'medno'=>$medno,
            'ingredient'=>$ingredient,
            'description'=>$description,
            'addinfo'=>$addinfo,
        ]);

        $msg = "Data deleted";
        $datamsg = response()->json([
            'success' => $msg
        ]);

        return $datamsg->content();
    } else {
        echo'{"error":{"text":" Medicine does not exist"}}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, You will need to post an HTTP request to your delete endpoint.

And you are correct, this should go in the alert 'yes' handler.

You would put something like this in there:

```
this.http.post('url-of-your-delete-endpoint', {id: 123})
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(res => {
    // success
    console.log(res);
  }, err => {
    // error
    console.error(err);
  });
```

This example is using [Angular HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Hopefully this gives you a start.

[Here](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-http-requests-fetching-data-in-ionic/) is another good guide on doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

All you need now is the call to the api endpoint. You can do this using either

1. **[Angular's HTTPClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)** or
2. **[Ionic Native HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http).**

You can choose whichever suits your needs. (I personally prefer Ionic Native HTTP to easily counter CORS problem)

One way to use them is by creating a function for api call in the `.ts` file using HTTP/HTTPClient like this for example (using Ionic Native HTTP):

```
async deleteData(){

      let url = 'http://localhost/api/api-endpoint-url'

      let params = {}; // for request params

      await this.http.post(url, params, {}).then(response => {

        console.log('from server: ', response);

      })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log('error: ',error);

      });

  }
```

and then call the function in the 'yes' handler:

```
confirmdelete() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm Delete',
    message: 'Do you confirm to delete?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Yes clicked');
          this.deleteData(); // call deleteData()
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response this is what I have tried  in yes  handler ` {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Yes clicked');
          this.deleteData(); // call deleteData()

         
        }
      } `

Comment: ** deleteData() funtion ** `async deleteData(){

        let url = 'http://192.168.0.40/clinic123/public/api/deleteMed'

        let params = {}; // for request params

        await this.http.post(url, params, {}).subscribe(response => {

          console.log('from server: ', response);

        })
        .catch(error => {

          console.log('error: ',error);

        });
}
`

Comment: I tried those and got this error. so how? polyfills.js:3 POST (my api)clinic123/public/api/deleteMed 405 (Method Not Allowed) –

Comment: probably caused by wrong HTTP method. for your API endpoint, which HTTP method did you use? (something like POST/GET/DELETE). if it's something other than POST, you need to change from ```this.http.post``` to the right method. for example, if you are using the DELETE method, change to ```this.http.delete```

Comment: in laravel I use GET method.

Comment: then, you need to change ```this.http.post``` to ```this.http.get```

Comment: `async deleteData(){

        let url = 'http://192.168.0.40/clinic123/public/api/deleteMed'

        let params = {}; // for request params

        this.http.get(url, params).subscribe((response) => {
          console.log(response);
      })
        .catch(error => {

          console.log('error: ',error);

      });
}`

Comment: i tried that but still got error _TypeError: _co.onChange is not a function_

Comment: subscribe and catch is not a function. I change then to subscribe because if I type then it will have an error property then not exist on type observable